Selenium + node on New Relic - javascript error: missing ) after argument list
I'm currently working out how to verify images are not broken on a specific page using New Relic's scripted browser capability. I'm able to gather the list of specific image elements then transform the unusual nature into a usable URL that, on their own, load the image as expected when put into a browser's URL bar. In short, manually, these images work and I can print the full URLs so I have the right ones.
What I've found, thus far, is that just sending a quick request to check if 200, 404, or some other HTTP response code is returned isn't all that easy within the confines of New Relic's implementation of Selenium and node. I looked through the node documentation and didn't find anything that stood out as doing what I want it to do. At least, not as a core module, and I haven't seen a way to include non-core modules within New Relic so I suspect that option is out. Instead of trying to import a node module, I thought I'd just use the Chrome fetch API to do the dirty work instead. It partially works, but I always get a Javascript error that doesn't make any sense to me.
In the script, I log the URL, which comes out properly. I also log what's returned from executeScript. I'm returned a promise, which I would expect should happen.
This is my script:
var assert = require("assert");
var url = require("url");

async function waitForPendingRequests(timeout) {
    await $webDriver.wait($webDriver.executeScript('return document.readyState == \'complete\''), timeout, 'waitForPendingRequests');
}

// Script variables
const BASE_URL = 'https://www.base.com';
var aemUrl = 'https://www.base.com/brands?no-age-gate';
var waitTime = 30000;
var imgElement = ($selenium.By.css('div.image-content-wrapper.flex.flex-col > img'));
var imageUrl = function(image) {
    return $webDriver.findElements(imgElement).then(function(images) {
        return image.getAttribute('srcset').then(function(link) {
            var srcUrl = new URL(BASE_URL+link);
            var imgUrl = srcUrl.href.split("%201x,", 1).flat(1);
            console.log('URL: '+imgUrl.toString());
            var response = $webDriver.wait($webDriver.executeScript(`await fetch(${imgUrl})`), 25000);
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        });
    });
};

$webDriver.get(aemUrl).then(function() {
    return waitForPendingRequests(waitTime);
}).then(function() {
    return $webDriver.findElements(imgElement).then(function(images) {
        images.forEach(imageUrl);
    });
});

This is what I get in the console log:
URL: https://www.base.com/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.base.com%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Fbase%2Fen%2Fbrand%2Fbrand-icons%2Finternal-brands%2F2023_08_01_Base_Homepage_Brand_Icons_Owned_numbers__209x209_Brand.jpg&w=256&q=75
Promise { <pending> }

This is what I would expect to get.
However, I also get this as an error, which I don't understand;
JavascriptError: javascript error: missing ) after argument list
  (Session info: chrome=117.0.5938.149)
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/app/synthetics-node-browser-runtime/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:539:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/app/synthetics-node-browser-runtime/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:647:13)
    at Executor.execute (/app/synthetics-node-browser-runtime/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:573:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Proxy.execute (/app/synthetics-node-browser-runtime/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:735:17) {
  remoteStacktrace: '#0 0x55e3d1b7c6b3 <unknown>\n' +
    '#1 0x55e3d18521e7 <unknown>\n' +
    '#2 0x55e3d185713e <unknown>\n' +
    '#3 0x55e3d1858caa <unknown>\n' +
    '#4 0x55e3d18d4e0f <unknown>\n' +
    '#5 0x55e3d18bb0c2 <unknown>\n' +
    '#6 0x55e3d18d4322 <unknown>\n' +
    '#7 0x55e3d18bae93 <unknown>\n' +
    '#8 0x55e3d188d934 <unknown>\n' +
    '#9 0x55e3d188e71e <unknown>\n' +
    '#10 0x55e3d1b41cb8 <unknown>\n' +
    '#11 0x55e3d1b45bf0 <unknown>\n' +
    '#12 0x55e3d1b5019c <unknown>\n' +
    '#13 0x55e3d1b46808 <unknown>\n' +
    '#14 0x55e3d1b1327f <unknown>\n' +
    '#15 0x55e3d1b6ae88 <unknown>\n' +
    '#16 0x55e3d1b6b059 <unknown>\n' +
    '#17 0x55e3d1b7b843 <unknown>\n' +
    '#18 0x7f32ff0faac3 <unknown>\n'
}

I know it's from the fetch call, but I don't understand why. To actually use the image URL I built a little earlier, I can't just use the variable without somehow 'injecting' it (for lack of a better term), otherwise it just gives me an error that imgUrl doesn't exist. I also tried ('fetch('+imgUrl+')), but that also didn't work correctly.
I need to resolve javascript error: missing ) after argument list, pull the HTTP response code from the promise, and link it all together such that if an image returns a 404, an error is thrown.
This is where I'm a bit stuck and not sure how to proceed. I looked for examples, but there really aren't any that are specific to New Relic, and anything I find on that argument error, they're not entirely relevant since I don't think I'm missing any opening or closing parentheses or braces.
The ultimate goal is to gather the URL, check for a 404, then fail if one is found. I'm reasonably certain this part can be handled with a catch block, though I'm not 100 percent how that would be done within the context of New Relic's implementation of Selenium + node.
